# Postman request from curl

Tags: curl, postman

Hi I am experimenting with my API through curl and I want to make same requests through postman.

```
curl -X POST http://MYADDRESS/xxx/pdf_reports
-H 'accept: application/vnd.xxx.v2'
-H 'cache-control: no-cache' 
-H 'content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW' 
-H 'postman-token: ATOKEN'
-F 'user[username]=XXX--__--AUSER@test.com'
-F 'user[password]=SOMEPASS'
-F file=@TEST.pdf
```

This is code generated by postman. When I use it in terminal, it works.
When submitting by postman, I receive authorisation error.
Do you have any suggestions what can cause the issue with authorisation?

Comment: did you try `user.username`instead of `user[username]` ?

Comment: This is how my api looks like. The fields are specified like that. The problem is tranlation of value from curl to normal string.

Comment: OK, did you change the body type to `application/www-form-urlencoded` ?

Comment: I've added all request. Also changed the issue - I don't want to translate --__-- but find out why does same request sent through postman doesn't work. curl generated by postman works with no problems.

Comment: Try out by setting in Authorization tab as *Basic Auth* and then provide credentials their.

Comment: @DeepakBhavale I've already found a solution to my problem. See answer below. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found solution: too many parameters added. Postman adds boundary automatically with multipart/form-data selected, thus no manual specification of it needed.